# Ask questions banned for unknown reason

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi)

I have been banned from asking questions on stack overflow, I don't understand why because there were no down votes on any of my questions or closed questions

Comment: Did you read the message you got informing you? Have you deleted a number of your questions?

Comment: Are you sure? I see a -1, -4, and a -6 questions on your account  and the rest are at 0. You don't have a single positively-scored question.

Answer (score 7):

[Your SO account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833898/keagan-ladds?tab=questions) has six questions with a total of one upvote and twelve downvotes.

Please see: [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi)

Comment: @MrLister You're not reading very carefully.  There is information in that post on what you can do.  I'm not going to repeat it for you here.